# Summary of functions in current file?

Tags: plugin-system, plugin-nerdtree

While working in various source files, (C, Ruby, etc.) I find that I'm often hunting around for functions. Is there a way to have an auto-generated HUD that lists the structure of the current file? It would be fantastic if it linked to different *parts* of the file, similar to how NERDTree links to different files. Or, similar to the side-navs in the screenshots here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16895610/gen-file-missing-incomplete-in-eclipse

Assuming that this doesn't exist as a plugin or something, how do people usually navigate around files like this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could try either [TagList](http://vim-taglist.sourceforge.net/) or [TagBar](http://majutsushi.github.io/tagbar/) but such a list could be generated as needed (no third party tool or configuration needed) with a simple:

```
:g/func/#
```

See `:help :global`.

If you don't mind a little bit of per-filetype configuration, the `:dlist` command could be used to list every function in the current file *and* included files:

```
:dlist /
```

See `:help definition-search`, `:help 'include'`, `:help 'define'`, `:help 'suffixesadd'`.

Comment: not a very smart approach though. Would rather have the screen splitted and read the fucntion list in a draft

Comment: Learned about dlist today, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing a regex as @romainl seem to be suggesting, You can have taglists installed and add the following to .vimrc:

```
nnoremap <C-l> :TlistToggle<CR>
```

Now by pressing `Ctrl + l` you'll show/hide the list of functions, structures and more.

Answer (score 0):

This works for my python files.

`zM` folds the file to the lowest number of lines, then `zo` unfolds the line that is folded to show functions in classes which can be searched, then when you want to look at a function content, goto its folded lines and unfold all with `zO`.

```
:help fold
```

Comment: You probably have foldmethod set to syntax, right?

Comment: well for python, indent is sufficient, i tried both and didnt see a difference

Comment: Ah, or indent, yes. I dont know that either is the default, so its worth mentioning in the answer.